# Are AutoCAD usage questions on topic here?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, questions

Are AutoCAD usage questions on topic here? [The CAD proposal didn't pick up steam and was closed](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80927/computer-aided-design-cad).

Comment: Fwiw, I've restarted the [CAD proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93545/computer-aided-design-cad).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not in a general no. But again if you ask a question about **graphic design** like the layout of a sign or something to that effect.

Note: It is extremely rare, so far, that the CAD or 3D questions are of anything other than how to use a feature of your tool. These questions are not really productive for us. But more they are not productive for the asker as they will get no answers.

Don't get me wrong I'm a seasoned CAD user. I used CAD applications nearly daily last year and every other day this year. I could with minimal research answer all of the 3D and CAD questions we have. It is just that i am no longer in a position where i can easily use all those apps freely. I do know how to use autocad... its just that i dont care much about it (as far as im concerned its obsolete, no aversion against obsolete things i do write postScript by hand).